# Computing Limit without Polar Coordinates

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

Let $f(x,y) = {\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}}$ if $x\neq -y$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ otherwise.

How can I compute $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y)$ 
without using polar coordinates tranformation? That is, using only the $\epsilon-\delta$ definitions or else some other algebraic trick?

Comment: **Hint:** $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}=(x+y)-\frac{2xy}{x+y}$. The first term goes to $0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. For the second term can you compare numerator with denominator etc...

Comment: To be perfectly fair, the $\delta-\epsilon$ limit definition constructs circles of radius $\delta$ around $(0, 0)$, so converting to polar is a very natural first step.